# How to install specific PHP version on Debian 9 (Docker)

Tags: php, docker, debian

I have a Debian 9 running on Docker. I need to install specific old version of PHP on it, for example *PHP 5.3.3* or older. It is not in official repo now (only 5.6).

Maybe it is simply installing in Dockerfile?

I have watched many answers and forums, but have found nothing what worked (only problems with libxml2)

I will be grateful to any of your advice ;)

Comment: Do you consider using one of the existing docker images with php, for example php:5.3-apache?

Comment: Download the deb files and manually install them.  https://web.archive.org/web/20120627075513/http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php5/